# Draggable scroll bar into a DataTable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have a DataTable with a SingleChildScrollView and it works fine, I can scroll with the mouse, but I would also like to have a draggable
scroll bar, does anyone know how to do it?

This is my DateTable with SingleChildScrollView Code:

```
    return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: DataTable(
      dataTextStyle:
          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      columns: [
        DataColumn(numeric: true, label: Text('Codigo')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Nombre')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Direccion')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Telefono')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Acciones')),
      ],
      rows: provider.sede.data
          .map((data) => DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text(data.codigo.toString())),
                DataCell(
                  Text(data.nombre),
                ),
                DataCell(Text(data.direccion)),
                DataCell(Text(data.telefono)),
                DataCell(Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        iconSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        splashRadius: 20,
                        tooltip: 'Editar',
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/crearSedes',
                              arguments: {
                                'direccion': data.direccion,
                                'telefono': data.telefono,
                                'nombre': data.nombre,
                              });
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                        iconSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        splashRadius: 20,
                        tooltip: 'Eliminar',
                        onPressed: () {
                          showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
                            Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
                              child: Text("Cancelar"),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            );
                            Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
                              child: Text("Eliminar"),
                              onPressed: () {
                                provider.EliminarSedes(
                                    data.codigo.toString());
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  elevation: 16.0,
                                  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(15)),
                                  ),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                  content: Text(
                                      "Se ha eliminado la sede ${data.nombre}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                          fontSize: 20)),
                                ));
                              },
                            );
                            AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                              title: Text("Eliminar"),
                              content: Text(
                                  "¿Seguro que quieres eliminar la sede ${data.nombre.toString()}?"),
                              actions: [
                                cancelButton,
                                continueButton,
                              ],
                            );
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return alert;
                              },
                            );
                          }

                          showAlertDialog(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
              ]))
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[My DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzo2l.jpg)

I would like something like this on my DataTable

[Draggable Scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJtZK.jpg)

I tried it with draggable_scrollbar but I hadn't success, it's possible into a DataTable?
May be I'm committing some mistake in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

- EDIT: You can use the [draggable_scrollable](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar) package on pub.dev

---

Wrap your SingleChildScrollView with the [Scrollbar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html) widget. You can nest any scrollable widget inside a Scrollbar and it will show the bar on the right side.

Comment: A scrollbar indicates which portion of a Scrollable widget is actually visible but haven't funcionality, I need a Draggable scrollbar, with a click draggable funcionality